# Crash from Parse when launching APK generated through export

Tags: parse-platform

We have integrated Parse application into our Android application. We were able to integrate and send a push notification in debug mode. However;when we try to export it as APK and test it through Test Fairy & Google Play we get the following error:

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ParseClassName annoation provided on class com.parse.lg
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

We made sure that parse JAR is bundled in APK and have added the configuration changes in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this after I have disabled proguard in the project.